# Multiple TABs for Text Snippets in Autohotkey

Tags: windows, scripting, autohotkey

I have been trying to do this for a while. I need multiple tabs in the same snippet. Let me explain. This is the standard format for hotkey that I use. It sends text when I press TAB.

```
:*:test`t::

         sendInput This is the test!

return
```

I would like to add multiple tabs functionality to this code. So when I press TAB it will go to parts of the displayed text and allow me to enter new text. Also when I press TAB again it will go to new part of the text.

Example code: When I press TAB once it will go to tab one, I will type some text and when I press TAB again it will go to TAB two. When there are no more TABs it will finish the snippet(When I press TAB it will behave as normal TAB). Also I would like to exit snippet when I press ESCAPE, text will still be written but TAB functionality will be gone, doesn't matter is all TABs are completed. This is very similar to snippets in text editor Sublime.

```
:*:test`t::

         sendInput This {TAB one} the {TAB two}!

return
```

Any help will be very appreciated.
Thanks xD.

Comment: Hotstrings won't work like that. Once your first tab fires the hotstring, it's done. You'll have to setup individual hotstrings for the following snippets. Or, approach the problem from another angle.

Comment: Any help with this will be awesome. Generally it does not have to be hotstrings. Anything with same functionality will be nice xD.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're going for, but maybe it'll get you started?

```
ini_snip := "var,file,section,key"
:*:inisnip::
{
    Send, IniWrite`,%A_Space%
    Loop, Parse, ini_snip, `,
    {
        KeyWait, Tab, D
        if (A_Index < 4)
        {
            Send, {backspace}%A_LoopField%`,%A_Space%
        } else {
            Send, {backspace}%A_LoopField%
        }
        KeyWait, Tab
    }
    return
}
```